# MYSQL How to update child table value with foreign key while insert data based on parent table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table, a parent table and child table. Child table has foreign key to parent table. I have successfully create the foreign key. But how to auto update field 'nama' based on parent table while I only insert 'id_parent' ?
I only tried :

```
INSERT INTO child (id_parent) values (1)
```

but field 'name' value is still NULL

Here my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nama` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `aa` (`nama`,`id_parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `aa` FOREIGN KEY (`nama`, `id_parent`) REFERENCES `parent` (`nama`, `id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for parent
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `nama` (`nama`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;
```

the parent table has data like this

```
INSERT INTO `parent` VALUES ('4', 'asa');
INSERT INTO `parent` VALUES ('1', 'batman');
INSERT INTO `parent` VALUES ('3', 'goku');
INSERT INTO `parent` VALUES ('2', 'robin');
INSERT INTO `parent` VALUES ('5', 'usu');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
KEY `aa` (`nama`,`id_parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `aa` FOREIGN KEY (`nama`, `id_parent`) REFERENCES `parent` (`nama`, `id`)
```

here you have created a `foreign key` relationship on two column i.e. `parent` (`nama`, `id`). In that case you can only insert **those combination** values in child table that are already in parent table. Remember, here foreign key is implemented by combining two columns, not on a single column.

Comment: I am still not quite understand about foreign key. So how can I auto update another field on same table with only insert one field based on another table ?

Comment: Check this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/ and if you have still problem, I will explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a Location TransId column in my child table. I have update the location name from the parent ti child table column. I done with the below

UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.CityName = Table_B.LocationDesc

from

```
<ParentTable> AS Table_A
INNER JOIN <ChildTable> AS Table_B
    ON Table_A.CityTransID = Table_B.TransID
```